# Can you combine a declarative and an interrogative sentence?

Tags: comma, punctuation, question

> Ich mag Äpfel und du?
> Ich mag Äpfel, und du?
> Ich mag Äpfel, du?

Is it correct to chain two main clauses that are of different modes?
Or should it be:

> Ich mag Äpfel. Und du?
> Ich mag Äpfel. Du?

For all of these the question is an elliptic of course.

> Ich mag Äpfel. (Und) Magst du Äpfel?

Answer (score 1):

Wenn man es ganz korrekt machen will, und auch stilistisch hohe Ansprüche hat, sieht die Lösung so aus:

> Ich mag Äpfel. Magst du auch Äpfel?

Hier sind die Aussage und die geschlossene Frage zwei sauber getrennte Sätze. Das Verb steht in der Aussage an Position 2 und in der geschlossenen Frage an Position 1. Das Adverb *»auch«*, das in der Frage auf das Verb wirkt, stellt den semantischen Bezug zur Aussage her, sodass beide Sätze als zusammengehörig empfunden werden.

Nachdem beide Sätze dasselbe Verb (eine Form von *»mögen«*) und dasselbe Akkusativobjekt (*»Äpfel«*) verwenden, kann man diese Wörter im zweiten Satz (also in der Frage) weglassen. Dadurch entsteht eine Ellipse, das ist ein unvollständiger Satz, dessen fehlende Bestandteile leicht aus dem Kontext ergänzt werden können:

> Ich mag Äpfel. Du auch?

Auch das ist noch stilistisch hochwertig.

---

Bei den folgenden Beispielen lasse ich vorerst noch offen, welches Satzzeichen zwischen Aussage und Frage stehen soll. Ich füge an der Entsprechenden Stelle vorerst einen Gedankenstrich ein, und werde später mehr darüber sagen. Satzzeichen sind nämlich nur ein Gliederungsmittel in der geschriebenen Sprache. Sprache wird aber hauptsächlich gesprochen, und in der gesprochenen Sprache gibt es so etwas wie Satzzeichen nicht.

Was es in der gesprochenen Sprache aber sehr wohl gibt, ist die Auswahl und die Reihenfolge der Wörter.

> 1. Ich mag Äpfel - und du?
> 2. Ich mag Äpfel - du?
> 3. Ich mag Äpfel - und?
> 4. Ich mag Äpfel - und - magst du Äpfel?

Die Variante 1 ist in der alltäglichen Umgangssprache allgemein üblich und sehr verbreitet. Man darf sie daher als korrekt ansehen. Stilistisch ist sie als fast gleichwertig einzustufen wie *»Ich mag Äpfel. Du auch?«*, aber eben nur fast.

Die Variante 2 liegt stilistisch auf einem deutlich niedrigeren Niveau als Variante 1. Die gesamte Frage ist zu einem einzigen Pronomen verkümmert und steht ohne Verbindendes Element hinter der Aussage. Das kann barsch und herablassend wirken, wobei diese Wirkung stark vom Kontext abhängt.

Variante 3 ist dann noch um eine Stufe unterhalb der Variante 2 anzusiedeln. Der Befragte wird in der Frage nicht einmal mit einem Pronomen erwähnt. Außerdem ist diese Formulierung mehrdeutig. Das gefragte Wort *»und?«* kann auch als *»na und?«* aufgefasst werden, was wie folgt gedeutet werden kann: *»Was geht dich das an?«* oder *»Kümmere dich um deinen eigenen Kram!«* Nur wenn Gestik und Mimik oder sonstige nonverbale Elemente der Kommunikation klarmachen, dass mit *»und?«* eigentlich *»Magst du auch Äpfel?«* gemeint ist, kann die Frage so verstanden werden. Von der Variante 3 ist also dringend abzuraten.

Variante 4 kann man, je nach Setzung der Pausen und der Betonung in zwei Subvarianten aufteilen (jetzt mit Satzzeichen):

> 4a. Ich mag Äpfel. Und? Magst du Äpfel?
> 4b. Ich mag Äpfel. Und magst du Äpfel?

Variante 4a beginnt wie Variante 3, also mit einem deutlich hörbar gefragten *»und?«* Darauf folgt - nach einer kurzen Pause - die Frage *»Magst du Äpfel?«* Diese nachgestellte vollständige Frage nimmt dem alleine stehenden *»und«* sofort alle negativen Konnotationen, und die ganze Phrase kann durchaus freundlich und interessiert klingen. Wir sind damit stilistisch wieder auf einem Niveau, das ungefähr der Variante 1 entspricht.

In Variante 4b wird das Wort *»und«* wie üblich betont (nämlich gar nicht), und es gibt danach auch keine Pause. Das wirkt zwar weder barsch noch herablassend, aber diese Wortfolge wirkt holprig und ungeschickt. Es wirkt, als würde der Sprecher die deutsche Sprache nicht korrekt beherrschen. Wenn man diese Frage hört, versteht man zwar genau was gemeint ist, insofern erfüllt der Satz die Grundanforderung von Sprache, aber das Wort *»und«* ist hier falsch verwendet, weil es nicht zwei gleichwertige Dinge verbindet, sondern verwendet wird, um eine vollständige Frage an eine Aussage anzuschließen.

---

Sehen wir uns nun die Satzzeichen an.

Welche Satzzeichen in Version 4 zu verwenden sind, habe ich bereits oben gezeigt. In 4a sind es insgesamt drei Sätze, in 4b nur zwei. Nachdem in beiden Fällen die Aussage stark von der Frage (bzw. den Fragen) getrennt ist, ist es angebracht, die Aussage durch einen Punkt abzuschließen udnd ie Fragen als separate Sätze zu notieren.

In Variante 1 würde ich persönlich auch einen Punkt machen, aber ein Komma wäre auch korrekt:

> Ich mag Äpfel. Und du?
> Ich mag Äpfel, und du?

Die Varianten 2 und 3 würde ich ebenfalls mit einem Punkt schreiben, aber ich würde generell davon abraten, sie überhaupt zu verwenden.

Comment: Variante 4a mit dem "Und?" kann mMn deutlich mehr Ungeduld (oder auch Neugier) ausdrücken als die neutral formulierte Frage 1.

Answer (score 0):

> <strike>Ich mag Äpfel und du?</strike>

> **Ich mag Äpfel, und du?**

> <strike>Ich mag Äpfel, du?</strike>

That latter phrase actually means a different thing, as *…, du?* is an interjection meaning *you got it wrong*.

> **Ich mag Äpfel. Und du?**

> <strike>Ich mag Äpfel. Du?</strike>

> Ich mag Äpfel. (Und) Magst du Äpfel?

That latter phrasing is valid but a loaded question.

Comment: "as ...,du? is an interjection meaning you got it wrong." Do you have a another example or a source? Either stehe ich gerade auf dem Schlauch, or this is complete news to me, I don't think I have ever heard of that.

Comment: Abkürzung von *…, du weißt schon?*

Comment: @HalvarF Agree. Must be a regional thing.